# git pull caused new commits which are not mine

Tags: git, rebase, pull

New to git. I did a git pull on a 'commonDev' branch I would like to merge my feature branch to. However after doing git pull on 'commonDev' I got conflicts on files which were not even mine. I resolved them manually however I would like to start fresh now on the commonDev' branch as it is saying I will have to merge those files which I manually modified.
Can I delete the branch locally using `git branch -D commonDev` and then checkout commonDev again so that I can merge my branch?
After reading thru other questions on SOF I see I should have used `git pull --rebase`. But now I already did `git pull` how do I safely delete the local or merge those files which are not mine?

Comment: Update: I tried to switch branch to another to delete my local 'commonDev' but I get `fileAbc: needs merge. error: you need to resolve your current index`

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`. When you run `git pull` you are really telling Git to run `git fetch` followed by a second Git command. Run the two commands individually and they should make more sense. Moreover, if one of the two steps *falis* (as happened here), you'll have a much better idea about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From your local *commonDev* branch, you can `git reset --hard origin/commonDev` to force your local *commonDev* branch to be the same as the remote *commonDev* branch. **This will wipe-out any changes you have made to your local *commonDev***.

Then, I'd suggest checking out your feature branch, rebasing it, then merging it.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will do it next time if I encounter such errors. For now I already aborted merge `git merge --abort` and then deleted the local commonDev. Then checked it out again so it was already up to date with the remote commonDev. Probably this is not a recommended practice but I was out of options.